# Dynamic FFI in Go

Tags: c, dynamic, go, ffi

Is it possible to **dynamically** load foreign C library (dll) and call its functions in Go?

I know there is `cgo` which is used to statically bind to C functions, but I'm interested in dynamic way.

Comment: See https://github.com/gonuts/ffi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: no. (at least not with gc, gccgo is gcc linkable however, so it might be possible)

Medium answer: However, you can statically bind, say, libffi or libdl and then use *it* to dynamically load other libraries.

Long answer: You can write go packages in C and ASM using the go toolchains C compiler and assembler (see src/pkg/runtime for example). So you could write a FFI in either C or ASM as a go package.

Edit: From the comments below (also CW now)

Alternatively, it can be done using the `syscall` and `unsafe` packages (easily in windows, but I imagine it would be harder in linux and not far off from the third solution above).

http://code.google.com/p/go/wiki/CallingWindowsDLLs

Comment: I like medium answer, maybe I'll try that. As for long answer, it's pitty that something like this is not part of the standard packages already.

Comment: Isn't it simply done by using http://golang.org/pkg/syscall/ LoadLibrary?  I remember someone had written code that allowed you to easily call any function inside a dll dynamically from Go, but I can't find that example anymore.

Comment: @jcao219 I hadn't seen that, but it's windows only. And you still need a way to call between the library routines and Go

Comment: You use GetProcAddress for that.  I thought the question is for a Windows solution because it said dll.  Here's an example I found: http://code.google.com/p/go/wiki/CallingWindowsDLLs